# When AutoResetEvent is Reset?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I still can't understand how `AutoResetEvent` works even after using it for years.

When it comes to `Set()`, should there be a part of code somewhere awaiting for `WaitOne()`?.

In other words.. if `Set()` has been successfully called before `WaitOne()`, will it be Reset automatically before `WaitOne()` and then I will miss Set?

or in other words - Does `WaitOne()` makes the flag reset or not?

Comment: It will release one thread, as per [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.autoresetevent?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: Do not update the question with a new question, this muddies the qa format of the site. Just post a new, clear question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.autoresetevent.set?view=netframework-1.1&viewFallbackFrom=netframework-4.8):

> The Set method releases a single thread. If there are no waiting
>   threads, the wait handle remains signaled until a thread attempts to
>   wait on it, or until its Reset method is called.

So to answer the questions:

- There does not have to be a `WaitOne` call, `Reset` will also un-signal the handle. (it would be bad design to make a class dependent on proper behavior of other classes.
- The handle remains signaled until a thread wait for the handle or `Reset` is called on the AutoResetEvent. So the Set will not be missed. A Set can be missed when two threads wait. See the documentation:

> There is no guarantee that every call to the Set method will release a
>   thread. If two calls are too close together, so that the second call
>   occurs before a thread has been released, only one thread is released
>   - as if the second call did not happen. Also, if the Set method is called when there are no threads waiting and the AutoResetEvent is
>   already signaled, the call has no effect.

- `WaitOne` does un-signal the handle but not every wait is guaranteed to do that (see previous remark)

From your questions I get the impression that it would help you to read the documentation more carefully and perhaps have a look at [the source code](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/threading/autoresetevent.cs)  You will see that the .NET classes wrap the Windows Event object. See [this article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8211/How-to-use-WIN32-Event-Kernel-Object) to get more information on how the Event object is/can be used.

Comment: The next part is probably also worth quoting :)

Comment: What if two threads are in WaitOne() and the Set() has signaled, then both threads will be released or only a one that received Set() first?

Comment: One thread will be released and then the event will be reset automatically, hence the name. There is a queue system of waiting threads, but I'm not sure you can access it.

Comment: @VitaliPetrov - I added more links to background information